# How do you do a python "for-each" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
foo = [3, 6, 3]
for a in foo:
    print a
```

How do I do that in ruby?

Comment: +1 for asking how to move the turtle in logo!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list = %w( a b c )

# there's a for statement but nobody likes it :P
for item in list
  puts item
end

# so you use the each method with a block instead

# one-liner block
list.each { |item| puts item }

# multi-line block
list.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foo = [3, 6, 3]
foo.each do |a|
  puts a
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = [1, 2, 3]
foo.each do |x|
    puts x
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your already have both correct answers about "for"-loop. But in Exactly your example, i'll use:

```
puts foo
```

Also you can use this puts' feature in such case:

```
puts array.map { |i| ...some code...; x }
```

instead of

```
array.each { |i| ...some code...; puts x }
```

for example, if you want to call puts only once.